# Modal Error property n does not exist on type component

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, agm

I'm quite new to angular. I'm trying to show my modal when I click a marker. It compiles succesfully and then outputs error. Sometimes doesnt compile succesfully. How can I fix this error? Is it because I set up jquery wrong? All of this code is in a component called HomeComponent. Code and error: [image] [image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The `m variable` is no need in this case, you can remove it.

If you need pass parameter you can set `#variable` and pass it to `markerClick`.

```
(markerClick)="markerClick()"

markerClick(){
  $("myModal").modal("show");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's expecting 1 input if I remove the m. If you dont mind could you show me how to do it?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fvqyNhcX , I tried to remove the marker passable parameter but the click didn't do anything.

Comment: with your html code, i think you don't need pass parameter, if you want you can pass $event as (markerClick)="markerClick($event)"

Comment: markerClick($event : MouseEvent){
    console.log($event)
    $("myModal").modal("show");
  } 

like this? It registers the click but doesnt pop up the modal, and I changed the html code as you said

Comment: did you install bootstrap for your app?

Comment: yeah I set it up when I started the project,  I have "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" in the angular json.